# Stripe charges the amount while creating a subscription. It should not happen

Tags: stripe-payments

We already have existing stripe customers, they have already paid the amount on different dates.

Now we would like to create a subscription option for those customers for recurring payments. But the problem is, it is charged immediately after the creation of the subscription. It is not considering the `billing_cycle_anchor` timestamp.

Sample code of subscription that I am using.

```
$stripe_subscription_response   =   $stripe->subscriptions->create([
            'customer'                  =>  $stripe_profile_id,
            'default_payment_method'    =>  $payment_method_id,
            'billing_cycle_anchor'      =>  $due_date_time_stamp, //Upcoming due date timestamp
            'items' => [
                ['price' => $stripe_price_info->id],
            ],
        ]);
```

Is there any way to stop the amount charge? while creating a subscription.

I have seen the below answer.
[Stripe charges twice every time i create a new customer and post a charge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193984/stripe-charges-twice-every-time-i-create-a-new-customer-and-post-a-charge)

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behaviour :

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#new-subscriptions

A request like that will charge the customer upfront for a prorated amount of the pricing plan, from the time of the API request to `billing_cycle_anchor`.

If you don't want them to be charged yet you could either pass `'proration_behavior' => 'none'` on that request, or set `'trial_end' => $due_date_time_stamp` instead of setting the anchor directly. Either approach avoids charging the customer(the latter creates a $0 invoice, the former doesn't).